# How to remove {'field__avg': when printing avg in Django templates

Tags: python, django

This should be a pretty simple question, but googling for it has been difficult, and I couldn't find the answer in the official documentation. I'm trying to average a field in Django, and I've got that all figured out, but when I print it in my template, I get this annoying "{'field__avg':" printing along with the actual value. How do I remove that and only print the actual value? Alternatively, how do I call that value so that I can use it in some logic?

views.py:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
def event_detail(request, slug):
    starsavg = UserLog.objects.filter(climb__slug=slug).aggregate(Avg('stars'))
    return render(request, 'event_detail.html', {
        'starsavg': starsavg, 
})
```

then in my templates I have:

```
{{ starsavg }}
```

Which outputs:

```
{'stars_avg': 2.75}
```

I want it to instead just output:

```
2.75
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to derive the average and also the template code you're using to print it.

Comment: See my above edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of the aggregate queryset is a a dictionary `{'stars_avg': 2.75}`. Just like for any other Python dictionary, you can access its values in a Django template by using dot notation. In this case it would be: `{{starsavg.stars_avg}}`.

Here are the docs on accessing values in templates using dot notation. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups

Otherwise, if you want to deal with the value in your view code, you can access it like you would  normal Python dictionary in Python: `starsavg['stars_avg']`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this in the shell and for some reason it did not work. Any idea why? I get an error that 'dict' object has no attribute 'stars_avg' (also tried 'stars__avg', which is the actual output.

Comment: It didn't work in the shell because Django template language is not Python,  and won't work in the shell. You need to use the Python method in the shell. Yes, if the actual output is `stars__avg`, then you need to use that.